# char** v *char[] in C

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, function-declaration

As I read through C code, I often times see this:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

but I always learned to do this:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

So, why would I use one over the other? I know they're technically different, but I don't see quite why I'd use one as opposed to the other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where [on earth] did you learn `char *argv[]`? It's _always_ been `char **argv`. Oops, ISO/C [c11] strikes again! Since the ultimate origin for `argv` comes from the kernel stuffing the data into userspace and pushing a pointer, `char **argv` seems more appropriate. But, even with `char *argv[]`, you can still do `++argv` and it works like `char **argv` [so a bit of a moot point]. But, I wrote my first C program in 1981, and I've been using `char **argv` ever since. And, the kernel will pass down: `int argc,char **argv,char **environ`

Comment: @Craig Estey, what? Realize they are 100% equivalent as parameters. So this talk always being one, and of kernel passing down one of the version? it's nonsense.

Comment: They are technically exactly the same. The type of `argv` is `char**` in both cases. Choosing one or the other is a matter of personal aesthetic preference.

Comment: @CraigEstey, possibly they got it from K&R 1ed, which uses the `char *argv[]` form for the second parameter to `main` in its examples.  That's been equivalent to `char **argv` (as a function parameter) pretty much forever, and definitely in ANSI C and *every* version of ISO C.

Comment: @CraigEstey I honestly have no idea where I learned that. I didn't use any specific course to learn C, so there's no sure way to know.

Comment: Perhaps `int main(int argc, char *argv[argc + 1])` would be more informative?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I mean yeah, but not nearly as informative as `int main(int argc, char *argv[argc + (int)pow((float)argc, 0.0)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, for the purposes of access to the arguments, those two notations are equivalent.

The `[]` notation may have a marginal benefit of distinguishing between a pointer to a single element and a pointer to an array; the `char**` can be misread as an out-parameter of type `char*`.

Unlikely with `main()`'s `argv` though.

Comment: So it is just a preference. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

From  the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)):

> 7 **A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted
> to "qualified pointer to type"**, where the type qualifiers (if any)
> are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.
> If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array
> type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
> corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
> element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

So these declaration of `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

are equivalent. If to exclude `main` that shall be declared only once you may declare the same function twice, like for example:

```
void f( char * [] );
```

and:

```
void f( char ** );
```

in the same translation unit. Moreover you even can declare the above function like

```
void f( char * [10] );
```

or

```
void f( char * [100] );
```

because in any case a parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to a pointer to the element type like

```
void f( char **  );
```

The same approach is used for parameters that have function types.

For example these two function declarations:

```
void f( void ( void ) );
```

and:

```
void f( void ( * )( void ) );
```

are equivalent because function parameters having function types are adjusted by the compiler to pointer types to the function types.

From the C Standard:

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as "function returning type" shall be
> adjusted to "pointer to function returning type", as in 6.3.2.1.